# What are the drawback to storing files in the /tmp folder when using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a node app that posts some files to the backend, I want to upload the, and get URI's to do this, I am using  multer and I am thinking of storing the files in the `tmp` directory.

What are the drawbacks to this?

1. Will I incure more costs and how can I avoid that?
2. When will the files be deleted from the `/tmp` folder? I want them to be deleted as soon as possible after uploading and getting their uris.

This is an open ended question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will increase costs.

You will probably want to delete them yourself, when you are done with them.  I don't think GAE will delete them (except when deploying a new instance) and you don't want to fill the disk.

The only downside I can think of is that the files are specific to an instance so only the same instance that put them there can use them.  If you are doing this in a single HTTP request you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the drawbacks to this?

Based on this documentation on [reading and writing temporary files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-temp-files?tab=python):

> All files in this directory are stored in the instance's RAM, therefore writing to `/tmp` takes up system memory.

> Will I incure more costs and how can I avoid that?

This would depend on the size on the file size in the `/tmp` as this would take up system memory. Pricing would still based on the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing). Please take note that pricing is still not final and would depend on your usage and taxes that would apply on the final billing.

> When will the files be deleted from the `/tmp` folder? I want them to be deleted as soon as possible after uploading and getting their uris.

Files written in `/tmp` are only available to the instance that created the files. You can either delete the instance, deleting the temporary files with it, or create a custom script that would manually delete the files once the tasks have been completed.